# how do stack works in Recursion

Tags: c

i don't understand that how stack works in Recursion. During Recursion the parameter of the function get pushed in the stack and return address also pushed on to the  stack.The return address and parameter is pushed in the same stack or the return address get pushed in other stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way is possible. The results are equivalent. The local variables of the function also need space which is managed like a stack, and this again can be the same stack or a different one. This is a possible way to implement a C function call:

- Push the function parameters to the parameter stack.
- Push the desired return address (generally the address of the instruction after the branch) to the return address stack.
- Branch to the function's address.
- Push the initial values of the function's local variables to the local variable stack.

And a corresponding way to return from the call:

- Pop the local variables from the local variable stack.
- Pop from the return address stack.
- Branch to the address that was just read.
- Pop the parameters from the parameter stack.

If instead of having three separate stacks, there's just one, the procedure above still works. Note that it works because the steps are ordered correctly: with a single stack, you need to do the pops in reverse order from the pushes, whereas with multiple stacks, the order only needs to be consistent within each stack.

In practice, most platforms use a single stack for everything, because it makes memory management easier. Before calling the function, the code creates a [stack frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#STACK-FRAME) by pushing both the parameters and the return address to the single stack. Pushing the parameters before the return address is typically easier because it uses a relative addressing mode to obtain the return address:

```
push parameter_1
push parameter_2
…
push program_counter + 2
branch my_function
; first instruction after returning
```

The first thing the code of the function does is to extend the stack frame to make room for its local variables. Concretely, “extend the stack frame” typically means adding the needed space to the register that points to the the top of the stack. Then, at the end of the function, the code loads the return address into a register, subtracts the length of the stack frame from the stack pointer, and branches to the return address.

There are a lot of possible variations and practical complications. The exact way to call a function is called a [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention). Most platforms define a calling convention so that code compiled with one compiler can call a function compiled with another compiler. The calling convention can be different for functions with different prototypes: for example, often, some arguments are passed in registers, and the layout of the stack frame may be different for variadic and non-variadic functions. However, some platforms support multiple calling conventions, which requires an additional non-standard annotation on function prototypes (such as [`__cdecl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) vs [`__stdcall`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall) on Windows).

One of the possible complications is a [shadow stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_stack). Most platforms use a single stack because it's easier to implement and there's less memory management overhead. However, a single stack has the downside that a bug in a function, such as a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) in an array that is stored on the stack, can easily cause it to overwrite the return address. A shadow stack is an extra copy of the return address in a return address stack which is separate from the main stack. When returning from a function, the code checks that the two copies of the return address are the same, and jumps to an error handler if they aren't. The reason to keep the return address in the main stack is for compatibility. It's the called function that pushes the return address to the return address stack, not the caller; that way the caller doesn't need to know whether the function that it's calling was compiled with shadow stack support or not. The called function gets the return address from the main stack.